# How to prove the linear independence for these functions?

Tags: linear-algebra

The functions are $1$, $x^2$ and $x$ are linearly independent.

I know the definition of linear independence i.e. I know that I must show that $a.1 + b.x^2 + c.x = 0$ is satisfied only when $ a=b=c=0$ but I don’t quite know how to proceed towards showing that.

I have only shown linear independence for a set of vectors 'till date so this is something I need help with.

Comment: **Hint** If $a+bx+cx^2=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, in particular, it vanish for $x=0$, $x=1$ and $x=2$...

Comment: When $x$ is $0$, I get $a=0$. How do I find the value of $a$ when $x \neq 0$ for example?

Comment: One way is to say that the equation $a+bx+cx^2=0$ does not have real roots.

Comment: If $a \neq 0$ then the polynomial is not the zero polynomial. The same argument applies to $b$ and $c$. Note that the fact they are polynomials is immaterial and you could use $x_k$ instead of $x^k$ to index the coefficients.

Comment: Use the Hint in comment 1 to create 3 simultaneous equations for $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Comment: @Surb so when $x=0$, I get $a=0$. When $x \in \mathbb{R} - 0$, does $a=0$ hold?

Comment: yes of course, it's a constant ! Now, you have $bx+cx^2=0$ for all $x$, so take $x=1$ and $x=2$ to conclude.

Comment: Yes, because the equation holds for all x. If not, a would be x dependent and not a constant, which is required in the definition of linear independence.

Comment: Yes right, thank you everyone, for some reason, the fact that the equation holds for all $x$ hadn’t registered but it makes sense now. So essentially in situations like these where the equation holds for all $x$, I can use particular values of $x$ to construct equations that would allow me to find the values of the constants involved.